# Overriding casting operation in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

In the code given below, when the **func** method is called with argument **d**(of type derived) it gets cast into **base&**. I want to know whether I can override this cast operation or not. I want to call some operation when this particular casting occurs in my program. Is it possible?

```
class base{};

class derived : public base{
    int a;
};

int func(base &a){
    printf("Conversion from derived to base&", &a);
}

int main(){
    derived d;
    func(d);
}
```

Comment: If this implicit conversion (a cast is an explicit conversion) presents problems, your class hierarchy is most likely not a good idea to begin with and needs rethinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A derived to base conversion is not a cast.

A cast is a notation for expressing a conversion.

Where you want a function to accept only a specific type of argument you can make it template, and use SFINAE like `std::enable_if`. Apart from that (which isn't always applicable) you can not in general suppress derived-to-base. But you can remove the derived class relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide an overload of func for derived& like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

class base{};

class derived : public base{
    int a;
};

int func(base &a){
    printf("Conversion from derived to base&\n");
    return 0;
}

int func(derived &a){
    printf("called with derived&\n");

    // defer to the base version if you wish
    return func(static_cast<base&>(a));
}

int main(){
    derived d;
    func(d);
}
```

but it's poor style and brittle (won't work for derived2, or derived3 when someone defines them).

A more correct (read: maintainable, elegant, and likely to prevent your colleagues loathing you) style would be to encapsulate the different actions in a virtual method within the base/derived hierarchy. Then the free function (acting on base&) defers to base's interface and allows the derived class to take care of itself:

```
#include <cstdio>

class base{
public:
    int func() {
        return handle_func();
    }

protected:
    virtual int handle_func() {
        printf("base&\n");
        return 0;
    }
};

class derived : public base{
    int a;

private:
    virtual int handle_func() override {
        printf("derived&\n");
        return base::handle_func();
    }

};

int func(base &a){
    return a.func();
}

int main(){
    derived d;
    func(d);
}
```